# setState() inside different function calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to use `setState()` in different functions. The crux is, I manipulate the same state attributes ('test', 'options') with different values, depending on the current state or usecase and call other inner functions (`this.doSomething()`).
The problem is in `function1()` where I call all functions one after another. How can I guarantee that the condition `'this.state.test' === '2'` in `function3()` is thuthy?

I know, `setState()` in asynchronous and there is a callback function but how can I use this callback when having multiple functions like in my setting? I don't want to use any "callback hell" and would like to know if there is any elegant way to achieve this...

Kind regards

```
function1() {
  ...
  this.function2();
  this.function3();
  this.function4();
  ...
}

function2() {
  this.doSomething();
  this.setState({
    options: 'abc',
    test: '2'
  });
  ...
}

function3() {
  this.doSomethingElse();
  if (this.state.test === '2') {
    this.setState({
      options: 'def'
      test: '3'
    });  
  }
  ...
}

function4() {
  this.doAnything();
  this.setState({
    options: 'xyz',
    test: '4'
  });
  ...
}
```

Comment: May be you can try cascading the functions 2, 3 and 4 with promises in `function1()` like `function2().then(function3).then(function4)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use promises or callbacks on finish.

Example with callbacks (in ES6):

```
function1() {
  ...
  this.function2(() => this.function3(() => this.function4()));
  ...
}

function2(callback) {
  this.doSomething();
  this.setState({
    options: 'abc',
    test: '2'
  }, callback);
  ...
}

function3(callback) {
  this.doSomethingElse();
  if (this.state.test === '2') {
    this.setState({
      options: 'def'
      test: '3'
    }, callback);  
  }
  ...
}

function4(callback) {
  this.doAnything();
  this.setState({
    options: 'xyz',
    test: '4'
  }, callback);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot. Will give it a try!

Comment: BTW: Using callback function worked for me. But I'm struggling with the promise idea of @redu. Does anyony have a working example for ES6 promises in React's setState() ? I just found this open thread https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2642.